# client pc install software without administrative rights

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, group-policy

I've a PC installed Win 7 and it is on AD domain network.

I can just logon as client user, cannot logon as AD admin or local admin.

So i cannot install any software. I've talked to my IT department and they said too many bureaucratic processes about the software installation. It's too boring and time-consuming situation.

I dont wanna disable AD and Group Policy permanently. Becasuse PC must stay in AD.

Maybe i can disable it temporarily but then i must enable it again.

Is there any software or sth else like using BIOS to pass over this limitation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no software that can do that and even if  you want to do so, you'll need local admin rights, which you don't have. BIOs will not take over local administrative/Domain rights.

To remove the PC from the domain, you'll need admin rights. Same thing to add it back in that domain.

In a nutshell, unless you have admin rights, you can't do anything.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tool like [Offline NT Password Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) to change the local administrator password to something different, then install/change what you want.

---

I would highly recommend not doing that because it could cost you your job and possibly land you in legal trouble.

The better alternative would be to listen to what your IT department says and not do what they say you're not allowed to do, regardless of "boring bureaucratic processes". They're there for a reason.